# How to prepare for a "grind" mathematics exam?

Tags: coursework

What I mean by the title is,
Right now I am in a course (required for my degree) whose content is mostly elementary combinatorics and probability.  But for whatever reason, the exams are very long---like, 16 questions, to be answered in 50 minutes, all of which require a small but nontrivial amount of setup.  And the lecturer likes to require that even the most trivial "steps" be justified.  So, a lot of writing.  The content is rather rote, but he likes to include little tricks and obscure the content of the question in analogies much the way elementary algebra problems do.

Anyway, the minutiae are not all that important.  The point is, it's been years since I've taken such a course (and nearly failed), hence I'm not at all sure how to prepare for such an exam.  Are there some common tricks?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, there are graduate students in my course so I am not sure what you mean by this...many times Ph.D. students in my institution are required to take such elementary courses, at which point they are very likely to encounter similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no *tricks* to passinging exams.
Only knowing the content, and being able to express it in a timely fashion.

With that said, tips on expressing your knowledge:

- Knowing the content makes you faster
- Know the layout of the exam,

  - some exams are ordered easiest to hardest (rare)
  - most exams are ordered by topic
  - Often they are ordered first by topic then within topic by difficulty. Eg Q1 has 3 subquestions, 1A is a freebe eg a definition, 1B is a standard question very similar to something done in class 1C is a significantly more challanging question.
  - You can learn the layout from past exams, or it may be described in the class before the exam (This is why you should always attend the last class of semester, intentional or otherwise tips on the exam)
- Do the set up clearly. Since you say the questions are phrased as analogies, Your first step should be extracting and writing down the key information.

  - Not just for the markers sake but for your own. Readign your notes is faster than rereading running text.
  - Eg. Noting down: "let n=10 Apples, let m=3 Farmers, problem is a From N chose M."
  - Longer problems it is also handy to write down a outline of the steps you will follow to solve.
- Know the markers true preferences and requirements. They are not always what they say they are. Because people don't always know themselves very well.

  - Eg I have had lecturers say "I will award 0 marks for the whole question if you make an error in a elementary part. At this level you must be able to do the simple early steps without making mistakes.", But in practice infact only deducted 10% for making such errors.
  - You learn the markers true style from looking back at how your past tests were marked (assuming you had any).
- **Practice Practice Practice.**

  - If you can get past exams to practice on -- even without answers. Do so. do as many as you can.
  - Save at least one to do timed trail on
  - Break others down to learn what you need to know.

Comment: +1 and accepted thanks.  Sorry, yeah, meant to say "tips for improving speed", not "tricks" per se.  Some of these strategies are very counter-intuitive to me, but I will try them and see how well it works.

Comment: You don't need to accept yet. You should leave it unaccepted for a while to attract more answers. Then you can choose the best.
What sounds un-intuitive?

Comment: Not unintuitive but counter-intuitive.  For instance, writing down the problem a different way...never heard of it before.  But I'll try it for sure.

Comment: Not writing down the whole problem. Just the key facts.